# Mastercard insurance vs regular travel insurance

Tags: payment-cards, insurance, road-trips

I am travelling for a 5-6 weeks road-trip from UK to Mongolia via Turkey, Iran, Turkmenistan, etc.

I am looking for travel insurance that would cover me on this journey. I am not looking for car insurance, only for personal travel insurance.

I have MasterCard Gold that already has a travel insurance for Europe. I can upgrade it to travel insurance for the whole World for ~30€ (would be valid for up to 60 days of travel).

At the same time regular insurance companies offer travel insurance for 6 weeks for ~110€ for the countries I am about to visit.

I perfectly understand that conditions and services might be different between my MasterCard Gold insurance and regular insurance company. But what I do not understand is why the price is so different?

Comment: Because MasterCard buys a huge amount of coverage, which results in a much lower price per person.  No different than volume purchasing of anything.

Comment: Also what you should check: Very often insurances from credit cards will only compensate for damages, if you have paid the whole trip through the credit card. So the CC company calculates the fees, which they get for the transactions as well.

Comment: Check for reviews from people who have been *paid out* by Mastercard for their healthcare costs. That's the only thing that matters in the end,

Comment: I don't think this question's answerable without knowing the differences between the policies' coverage, if any.